# Как в элементе списка удалить ненужную часть текста?

Tags: python-3.x

У меня есть некий список, где есть следующие элементы:

```
results = ['A3261/22 5525N03755E025\nA) UUDD B) 2206180000 C) PERM\nE) \nSOURCE: UUUUYNYX', 'A2754/22 5525N03755E005\nA) UUDD B) 2205190905 C) 2212312359 EST\nE) AD ELEMENTS CLSD DUE TO REPAIR']
```

И таких однотипных элементов много. Все они начинаются c буквы `A 4 цифры`. Мне нужно из каждого элемента удалить промежуток между началом и до буквы А со скобкой `A)`. Остальную часть элемента сохранить в этом или новом списке. Можно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну так и делайте в лоб:

```
results = ['A3261/22 5525N03755E025\nA) UUDD B) 2206180000 C) PERM\nE) \nSOURCE: UUUUYNYX', 'A2754/22 5525N03755E005\nA) UUDD B) 2205190905 C) 2212312359 EST\nE) AD ELEMENTS CLSD DUE TO REPAIR']

new_res = [line[line.index('A)'):] for line in results]
```

Comment: помогло, спасибо!